# Clarifying Pointer Notation

Tags: c

In going over some C code I've encountered the following as examples.

```
*(dates +2) I get that this is the 3rd element of the array
```

.

```
*dates +2   2 added to the value of the 1st element.
```

Is there a reason for using this notation over:
dates[2]

dates[2] seems clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `*(dates +2)`, `2` is added to pointer `dates` and then the incremented pointer is dereferenced while in `*dates +2`, pointer `dates` is dereferenced first and then `2` is added to the dereferenced value.

```
        +-------+-------+-------+-------+
        |       |       |       |       |
dates   |  2    |   5   |   6   |   10  |
        +-------+-------+-------+-------+
          x100     x104    x108   x10C
```

In above expressions `dates` will be converted pointer to the first element, i.e. `dates[0]` of `dates` array. Address of `dates[0]` is `x100`. Therefore,
`*(dates + 2)` means: add `2` units to the base address `x100` and then get the value stored at `x108`. Result will be `6`.
`*dates + 2` means: get the value at base addess `x100` and then add `2` to that value. Result will be `2 + 2 = 4`.

Comment: @haccks-- 2 is added to the dereferenced value, as in if the value was 2 i would now have 4, or is it chasing the address that was pointed to?

Comment: I am glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 5):

The brackets, completely as you would expect, dictate the priority of the operations.

`*(dates+2)` will add to the pointer `dates` creating a new pointer. How much the pointer is incremented depends on the size of the type of the data type the pointer points to, for example if `dates` is a of `char *` type, because a `char` is 1 byte, `dates` is incremented by 2. However, if `dates` is a pointer to a 64 byte structure, then 128 will be added to the pointer. Either way, the idea is that when performing maths on a pointer, the new value of the pointer will align with another valid bit of data (unless you over or under run a buffer of course). Once the pointer maths is complete the pointer will be dereferenced and the value at the new pointer returned.

In the case of `*dates+2` there is no pointer maths, the value of the pointer is returned and 2 is added to it.

The more common notation for `*(dates+2)` is `dates[2]`.

Comment: For case 2 unless dates points to an integer-ish *dates + 2 won't compile.

Comment: Absolutely, yes, thanks, I deliberately didn't go there just because it didn't seem particularly important to the explanation and I didn't want to get into what it did and didn't work for. I knew there was a word I was looking for, and it was integer-ish :)

Comment: Feel free to steal my brilliant terminology!

Answer (score 1):

If `dates` is an array,

```
*(dates + 2)
```

is the *third* value in the array, because array indices start at zero. `dates` is really a pointer to the first value in the array, and adding `2` to it moves the pointer along to the third position. You can also write this as `dates[2]`.

On the other hand,

```
*dates + 2
```

is `2` bigger than the first value in the array. Here we are just getting the value the pointer points to, and adding `2` to that value. You can also write it as `dates[0] + 2`.

For example, if the values in the array are `10`, `100` and `1000`, `*(dates + 2)` is `1000`, whereas `*dates + 2` is `12`.